# Blog and news intertwined - Join or Union or something else?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I have 4 tables.

```
news:                news_link:            blog
---------            -----------           ---------
news_id,             news_link_id,         blog_id,  
news_title,          news_link_news_id,    blog_artist_id, 
news_content,        news_link_artist_id   blog_title, 
news_image,                                blog_content,  
news_date,                                 blog_date, 
news_sticky_status,                        blog_date_edited, 
news_sticky_order,                         blog_status,       
news_status,                               blog_keywords
news_keywords, 
news_date_edited
```

The other table is for artist

I have no problems performing basic joins to link the news items to the artist using the news_link.

My blog table has the artist_id within it.

I want to display the blog entries by date on a specific artist page, and have the news items that are related to that artist appear with in the blog item.

Here's the output I want:

```
title, date, content, status
```

I have tried some joins. Do I need a union? The tables have different labels, and the news table would need the news_link join to make sense.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Post more of your schema - at least the foreign keys. But in a nutshell, using `JOIN` is the way to go.

Comment: News - news_id, news_title, news_content, news_image, news_date, news_sticky_status, news_sticky_order,news_status, news_keywords, news_date_edited

Comment: news_link - news_link_id, news_link_news_id, news_link_artist_id

Comment: blog - blog_id, blog_artist_id, blog_title, blog_content, blog_date, blog_date_edited, blog_status, blog_keywords

Comment: For this page, i only need: title, date, content, status. But I need to know when it is a news item as apposed to a blog item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a `union` is needed, something like this:

```
<?php
$artist = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['artist']);
$query = 
"SELECT is_news, title, date, content, status FROM (  
  SELECT
      1 as is_news
    , a.artist_id as id 
    , n.news_title as title
    , n.news_date as date
    , n.news_content as content
    , n.news_status as status
  FROM artist a
  INNER JOIN news_link nl ON (a.artist_id = nl.news_link_artist_id)
  INNER JOIN news n ON (n.news_id = nl.news_link_news_id)
  WHERE a.artist_id = '$artist'
UNION
  SELECT 
      0 as is_news
    , a.artist_id as id
    , b.blog_title as title
    , b.blog_date as date
    , b.blog_content as content
    , b.blog_status as status
  FROM artist a
  INNER JOIN blog b ON (a.artist_id = b.blog_artist_id)
  WHERE a.artist_id = '$artist'
) s
ORDER BY s.id, s.date";
```

The `is_news` will be `1` for news items and `0` for blog items.

If you select multiple artists the query will sort the outcome per artist.

Comment: Thanks Johan. The Artist ID is already there as $artist_id - passed over in a $GET - This sort of joining and union is new to me so its a bit confusing. Where would I place me $artist_id and what are the a. n. b. s. in the statement for? Thanks again

Comment: The a,n,s are aliases for `artist`, `news` etc. So I don't bruise my fingers. The union glues the two selects together and there is an other select which intermixes the `union`ed results sorted by date.

Comment: Unless you're desperate to keep the `id` field out of the resultset for some reason, that outer select is not needed. You can simply specify the ORDER BY clause after the last UNIONed query.

Comment: @djacobson, but that will only sort the last unioned select, not the first and I want them to be mixed up, unless you mean `(select... union select ...) order by id`

Comment: ahh, this is making my head hurt! I have never used Union before and I'm finding very confusing... I have put this in my page and check the naming but I cannot get it working at all yet. Am following the query with the normal $result and $num and while but it is failing at the $num_rows

Comment: @Greybeard, you can use each (inner) select individually the union just glues them together. Run them separately first and see if they work with your fields.

Comment: @Greybeard, anyway forgot a `,`, please try the query again.

Comment: ok, the , has helped, I am now getting the while loop doing something. How would I call the results I tried $s['date']; for example but that didn't work...

Comment: Ok, this seems to be pretty much exactly what I was looking for! I have order the results by date DESC and the different types (news & blog) are intertwined. Thie only thing is how can I tell if I am getting a news or blog item so that I can style the post slightly differently

Comment: Thank you so much for that help! That has completely answered what I was looking for and taught me a new way of doing this at the same time!